# Ruby array to reject or delete if similar value is found during array merge

Tags: ruby

How do I delete the earlier array value if similar values exist? Here's the code I use:

```
def address_geo
    arr = []
    arr << do if do
    arr << re if re
    arr << me if me
    arr << fa if fa
    arr << so if so
    arr << la if la
    arr.reject{|y|y==''}.join(' ')
end
```

Given the following values

```
do = 'I'
re = 'am'
me = 'a'
fa = 'good'
so = 'good'
la = 'boy'
```

The above method would yield:

```
I am a good good boy
```

How should I write the array merge to reject `fa` and just take `so` to yield:

```
I am a good boy
```

Many thanks!

Comment: 1) "do" is not a good name for a variable in Ruby. 2) Can these values be nil or are always strings?

Comment: `do` is just an example of variable name, sorry. :) Yes, they can be nil.

Comment: you want to remove all duplicates or only consecutive ones?

Comment: If possible, keep the latest one. But your solution looks complicated. I can sacrifice that if the solution is simpler.

Comment: Victor, it's not a matter of "complicated", removing all duplicates or removing only consecutive duplicates is quite different. I don't understand "keep the last one" as an answer to this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Array#uniq](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq)

```
> arr = ['good', 'good']
> arr.uniq
=> ['good']
```

As per @tokland's suggestion, if you wanted to remove only consecutive duplicates, this would work (and support ruby 1.8).  By building a new array using `inject` we can filter out each string that is either `empty?`, or the same as the previous string.

```
> %w(a good good boy).inject([]) do |mem, str|
>   mem << str if !str.empty? && mem[-1] != str
>   mem
> end
=> ['a', 'good', 'boy']
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to remove consecutive elements of the array, uniq removes all duplicates regardless of position.

Answer (score 2):

You you can remove consecutive elements in the array with [Enumerable#chunk](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
strings = ["hi", "there", "there", "hi", "bye"].select { |x| x && !x.empty? }
strings.chunk { |x| x }.map(&:first).join(" ")
#=> "hi there hi bye"
```